# Pass value between same controller with different divs

Tags: angularjs

i don't no how do i explain my question,
ok let me try,

How to pass value from another `div` with same `controller` name?

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="filterBy" ng-options="filtration.title for filtration in filter_preferences"></select>
</div>
---------------------------------------------------
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="filterBy" ng-options="filtration.title for filtration in filter_preferences"></select>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="vals in datas | filter: vals.completed = filterBy.value">{{vals.title}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

From the second `div` when i filter i works fine, but the same filter i've applied on the top with same `controller` but it doesn't work.

[**DEMO PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DzdeaJCVohyuJYu0uTde?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that under each `ng-controller` it's creating a new $scope. This means they don't share `$scope` at all, and there are two different controller instances as well.

So, to communicate between two controllers, the common practice is to use a service.

[I've updated your plunk with a *very basic* example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0PCjWP6V8Z4o0DLWihJ6?p=preview)

The idea is that you create a service like:

```
app.value('sharedData', { filteredBy: true});
```

Then inject it into your controller and put it on your scope like so:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, sharedData) {
  $scope.sharedData = sharedData;
});
```

Then after that you'd use it as your ng-model value and your filter:

```
<select ng-model="sharedData.filteredBy" ng-options="x.value as x.title for x in filter_preferences"></select>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="vals in datas | filter: { completed: sharedData.filteredBy }">{{vals.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

From there it will work because both controllers (and $scopes) now have an instance of the same object... your `sharedData` service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify 
    ng-controller="myCtrl"
where the ng-app is and remove all the other ng-controller statements. This is because whenever you are trying to do ng-controller in individual div it is creating a local scope for that particular div and then any change in the dropdown is refreshing that local scope.

Code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div >
    <select ng-model="$parent.filterBy" ng-options="filtration.title for filtration in filter_preferences"></select>
  </div>
---------------------------------------------------
  <div>
    <select ng-model="$parent.filterBy" ng-options="filtration.title for filtration in filter_preferences"></select>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="vals in datas | filter: vals.completed = $parent.filterBy.value">{{vals.title}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Controller Code change donw:

```
 $rootScope.filterBy = $scope.filter_preferences[1];
```

Earlier it was:

```
 $scope.filterBy = $scope.filter_preferences[1];
```

**UPDATE:**

You can have the filterBy variable on the rootScope rather than the local scope. So that any changes to the local scope will be done at the root level and changes will reflect everywhere

Tried this in your plunker and it is working.

Comment: Thx for the reply but i can't do that coz between those 2 divs i've other controller written in it. Actually in the above case the first div is in the Header and second div is in the main section so can't write `ng-controller` in the `body` tag.

Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Updated the answer to have it as a parent scope. Please try it in your plunker to verify the changes.

Comment: No... do not use $rootScope to contain data. Global scope is evil.

Answer (score -1):

You could not mention controller twice under ng-app